# How to avoid override of a CSS class in deployment

Tags: css, reactjs, web-deployment

I have this css class `.number` in my React app which I use for numbers in a code editor. This style works perfectly locally, when I start the app with `npm start`. However, when deployed, this `.number` class gets overridden by some other `.number` class, which I have no idea where it comes from, it's no where in my code, and it breaks my style. Тhis is the style from my deployed app (pic 1). The first `.number` is my class, defined in `index.css` and this other is defined in `other.sass` but this file doesn't exist in my code.

[image: deployment style]

The second photo describes the style used in my local app. As you can see, this style and that from `other.sass` do not correspond. This is the code as well:

```js
.number {
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 9999px;
    display: inline-flex;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
```

Do you happen to know what is the potential reason for this kind of bug, how can I debug it and how can I fix it?

[image: local style]

Comment: In what order did you include the css files? Css is read from top to bottom, with the latter always overriding the whatever is writen above.

Comment: Hm, `index.css` is the last styling file I see in my structure. I have another folder called `styles` but it's above `index.css` and class with name `.number` doesn't exist anywhere in that `style` folder.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like some kind of bundler (webpack, parcel) or postprocessing (PostCSS, ...) is runnning via an npm script and generates the "confusing" part which you don't understand and is wrong here.

I would first try to understand which npm script runs when you deploy the app to find out which process generates the interfering class and fix it there. Usually, the command for this script can be found in the `package.json` in the `build` script.

If this does not work, simply rename the `.number` class to `.example-number` to give it a higher specificity, so that the correct styles are being applied.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Sadly I can't seem to rename `.number` to some other name because this is an inner class from a component I installed via `npm`. This problem occurred recently, before that the style was correct.